# Coherent sheaves with no cohomology over a hypersurface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, coherent-sheaves

Let $X_d \subset \mathbb{P}^{n+1}$ be a smooth hypersurface of degree $d$. How one can describe all coherent sheaves on $X_d$ with no cohomology i.e.
$$
H^i(X_d, F) \cong 0,
$$
for all $i \in \mathbb{Z}$. For example, is it possible to describe the corresponding graded modules? More generally, how to describe all objects with such property (replacing cohomology by hypercohomology) in the bounded derived category?

The most interesting case for me is a cubic surface in $\mathbb{P}^3$.

Comment: Do you know a single non-zero  example of such a  coherent sheaf $F$  on any hypersurface of any degreee on any  projective space?

Comment: For example, any non-trivial degree $0$ line bundle on a plane cubic.

Comment: Correct! If $F_r$ is the Atiyah unique indecomposable  vector bundle  of rank $r$ and degree $0$ with a non-zero section  on your curve,  and if $L$ is an arbitrary non-trivial  line bundle of degree $0$, then the rank-$r$ vector bundle $F_r\otimes L$ also has the property you require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cubic surface (at least over $\mathbb{C}$) has a full exceptional collection. In fact many full exceptional collections. One of them consists of sheaves 
$$
(O_{e_1}(-1),\dots,O_{e_6}(-1),O(-2\ell),O(-\ell),O)
$$ 
in the standard notation. Consequently, the objects of the derived category whose hypercohomology vanish are just objects of the subcategory generated by the subcollection
$$
(O_{e_1}(-1),\dots,O_{e_6}(-1),O(-2\ell),O(-\ell)).
$$